# Paint modifier FillBounds doesn't scale the drawable specified in the painter

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using JetPack Compose `1.5.3`.
I have the below code.
The `drawable` is has follow: width `360dp`, height `110dp`. It's a vector drawble.

When I use `ContentScale.FillBounds` I expect the drawable to fit in the bounds of the `CenterAlignedTopAppBar` which are calculated automatically.
Instead of that, the paint is drawn in full size (`110dp`). This results in the Text not being centred and being cut if I don't apply the `20dp` top padding.

To note: If I change the height of the drawable to something small (like `10dp`) then `ContentScale.FillBounds` works as expected as the image source is now smaller than the size of the `CenterAlignedTopAppBar`.

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to achieve what I want?

**Code:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun CustomHeader(titleString: String) {
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.mediumTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = Color.Transparent,
            titleContentColor = Color.White,
        ),
        title = {
            Text(
                text = titleString,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
            )
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .paint(
                painter = painterResource(
                    id = R.drawable.bg_waves_short,
                ),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            )
    )
}
```